# removeFromSuperview() doesn't work

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uiview

I have the following class to add and remove an activity indicator view:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewControllerUtils {

var container: UIView = UIView()
var loadingView: UIView = UIView()
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

func showActivityIndicator(uiView: UIView) {
    container.frame = uiView.frame
    container.center = uiView.center
    container.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(rgbValue: 0xffffff, alpha: 0.3)

    loadingView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80)
    loadingView.center = uiView.center
    loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(rgbValue: 0x444444, alpha: 0.7)
    loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
    loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40);
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
    activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: loadingView.frame.size.width / 2, y: loadingView.frame.size.height / 2);

    loadingView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    container.addSubview(loadingView)
    uiView.addSubview(container)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}

func hideActivityIndicator(uiView: UIView) {
    print("hideActivityIndicator called")

    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
    loadingView.removeFromSuperview()
    container.removeFromSuperview()
}

func UIColorFromHex(rgbValue:UInt32, alpha:Double=1.0)->UIColor {
    let red = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/256.0
    let green = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/256.0
    let blue = CGFloat(rgbValue & 0xFF)/256.0
    return UIColor(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:CGFloat(alpha))
}

}
```

I call the function in tableview and in view as well in the following way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ViewControllerUtils().showActivityIndicator(uiView: self.tableView)

    invitedEvents()
}
```

After loading the data I try to remove the activity indicator, but it is not removing.

```
func invitedEvents() {
     //calling firebase
     DataService.ds.REF_USER_CURRENT.observe(.value, with: { (snap) in
        ViewControllerUtils().hideActivityIndicator(uiView: self.tableView)
     })
}
```

When the tableview is loading is printing that hideActivityIndicator was called, but it not removing from the view.

I call the functions in a view as well and the same result: showActivityIndicator is working, hideActivityIndicator doesn't work.

I call the functions in a view with the following parameters:

```
  ViewControllerUtils().showActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)
  ViewControllerUtils().hideActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)
```

Does anybody an idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime if you write `ViewControllerUtils()`, you are creating the new instance of ViewControllerUtils class and hence once you show the activity indicator using one instance , you have to get the same instance of activity indicator to remove it with which you have added it. So you can make the `ViewControllerUtils` as singleton class and hence use it.

```
class ViewControllerUtils {
    static let shared = ViewControllerUtils()
    private override init() {
    }
}
```

Now call your methods like this ..

```
ViewControllerUtils.shared.showActivityIndicator(uiView: self.tableView)
ViewControllerUtils.shared.hideActivityIndicator(uiView: self.tableView)
```